# Is there a firewall for windows 7 that allows you to write your own rules?

Tags: windows-7, firewall

Like iptables or ipfw?

I've tried wipfw but it doesn't work on windows 7 (at least not for me).

Comment: Pretty much any firewall lets you do this, from my experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends how complicated you're intending to make these rules, but I've found the built in Windows 7 firewall to be sufficent.

Just make sure you are accessing the "Advanced Security" version and you can set port blocking / program blocking / etc, both for in- and out-bound connections.

I think you'll find in under:
Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Windows Firewall with Advanced Security
Or possibly by sticking **wf.msc** in to the run box.

Comment: Ah that might be what I need, I'll check it out

Comment: Wow that does exactly what I want, except I have about 200 ip addresses I need to add, hopefully there is some way to import these?

Comment: Nevermind! 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771920(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_1_export

Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fireBwall](http://firebwall.com), which I develop.

It allows you to write your own modules for filtering packets in C#, allowing for the firewall to do exactly what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. It's called Comodo Firewall. The settings are really straight forward and easy to use and plus its free :)